# Unit testing out parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Below is my unit testing code I have written to test my output, the Msg function will not return any result but return a string using out:

```
   string = "testing"
    string id = string.Empty; 
    string idExpected = "1"
    target.Msg(string, out id)
    Assert.AreEqual(idExpected, id);
```

Should I put anything into id? It is a output.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler forces a method with an `out` parameter to assign a value to the parameter so you should not initialize it at all:

```
var str = "testing";
string id;
target.Msg(str, out id); // Msg will always initialize id.
```

Answer (score 1):

No if it is out - nothing will go in it will make no difference.